# Wrong result for a multiplication

Tags: javascript, multiplication

I have run the following code in several browser console and I had the same result everytime :

```
>>> (17.06 * 100) === 1706
false
>>> (6.06 * 100) === 606
true
```

This is not logic.

Where does the problem come from ?

Comment: Did you consider viewing the result of the multiplication? That would seem like a sensible first step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a floating point rounding error.

In JavaScript, `17.06 * 100` !== `1706`, it's `1705.9999999999998`.

If you want a detailed explanation, check out [this article](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

If you want the functionality, use `Math.round()`:

```
>>> (Math.round(17.06 * 100) === 1706)
true
```

Comment: Why the downvotes?! This is the correct answer, surely?